# Match / Add follow path to imported 3d cylinder tube mesh object

Tags: mesh, path

I have a scanned 3D mesh object, that looks like a curved cylinder, imported into blender and I would like to add a path to it, so I can follow that path with another object (like in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u1jAqZyxsNA) example).

Is it possible to automatically create a path, centered in the cylinder tube, which follows the tube from top to bottom?

[image]

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific. I am not able to understand what your problem is or what it is tthat you want to achieve. Please provide more information if possible add images too.

Comment: sorry for the unspecific description, I hop it is clearer now